# Django constraint on Foreign Key field 'startswith'

Tags: python, django, orm, constraints, startswith

I have got problem with Django constraint. I want to create constraint on foreign key field to check if it starts with user_id but Django think "__startswith" is a lookup option. Am i wrong with constraint syntax or it is Django problem?  Probably i have tried to do this constraint with raw SQL and it works.

Have got this error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: startswith`

I have this Models:

```
class PrivateModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255, default="", editable=False)
    _owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Genre(PrivateModel):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Book(PrivateModel):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="book_genre_owner_constraint",
                check=Q(genre_id__startswith=F("_owner_id"))
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Did you tried with just the string ``` check=Q(genre_id__startswith="_owner_id")``` ?

Comment: @0x30c4 yes i did, the same problem occurred.

Comment: Does `check=Q(genre__id__startswith=F("_owner_id"))` solve the problem?

Comment: @R. Steigmeier No, it doesn't. You cannot use join in constraints so it doesn't work.